# Mana regen upgrade set interval

Tags: javascript, html

After I press the Mp regen skill tree button it should minus 1 from skillpoints then add 1 to Manapoints. Then I need to store that then run a set interval thing but I can't get it to work correctly. My function seems ok but I can't replicate what I did in Python to work.

http://prntscr.com/nsm5yy

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this; I'm really new at set intervals. I did try this:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    ManaPointsregen(Mpregen);
}, 1000);
```

This is my JavaScript function for Manaregen (this is my second try with a different method but still can't get it to work):

```
var rebirths = 0;
var HitPoints = 0;
var MaxHitpoints = 10;
var ManaPoints = 0;
var MaxManapoints = 10;
var SkillPoints = 0;

function buyRebirth() {
    var rebirthCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
    if (cookies >= rebirthCost && rebirths < 1){
        cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
        HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
        ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints + 1;
        rebirths = rebirths + 1;
        document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
        document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
        document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
        document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;
    }
    if (cookies >= rebirthCost)
    if(rebirths >= 1){
        cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
        rebirths = rebirths + 1;
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints +1;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
        document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
        document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;

    }
    var nextCost5 = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
    document.getElementById('rebirthCost').innerHTML = nextCost5;

    }




var Mpregen = 0;

function Manaregen(){
    if (ManaPoints < MaxManapoints && rebirths >- 1 && MaxManapoints >=0){
        ManaPoints = ManaPoints +1;
        set.interval( Manaregen, 1000);
    }
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;

}

function ManaPointsregenbuy(){
    if (SkillPoints > 0 && rebirths >=1)
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
        Mpregen = Mpregen +1;
        set.interval(Manaregen, 1000);

    document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;
    document.getElementById("Mpregen").innerHTML = Mpregen;
}
```

JavaScript Setinverval:

```
var cookies = 0;

function cookieClick() {
    cookies = cookies + Strength;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
    checkCursor()
}
var UP_INTERVAL = 1000; 
setInterval(cookieClick, UP_INTERVAL);
```

html button code: (I'm not using the button Id for anything yet)

```
<button id="Mpreg" onclick="ManaPointsregenbuy">Mp regen</button>
                <br />
```

I expect after buying a Mp regen from skill tree:

http://prntscr.com/nsmdmd

For my mana to go up by 1 every 1000ms (simulate mana regen) until it reaches My max mana. But the actual output the button does nothing. I have no idea how to set up a working setinterval function to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
onclick="ManaPointsregenbuy"
```

should be

```
onclick="ManaPointsregenbuy()"
```

Then you have several lines like

```
set.interval(.....)
```

The correct syntax for setting an interval looks something like this

```
var myInterval = setInterval(callbackFunction, 1000);
```

This like will set an interval, that can be canceled with

```
clearInterval(myInterval)
```

You can find more info at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Thanks . I will comment if it works trying it now just got home from work.

Comment: This is not working or im formatting It incorrectly.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nt2nd9       I have no idea what i'm doing wrong sigh. I Just want a working way to upgrade my mana regen with a skill point.

Comment: At the moment im trying to move every different tab in my game to a different JavaScript i'm hoping that helps. since the beginning i haven't been able to get the set interval stuff to work correctly. an example would help me alot. i tried to google one for a bit but the one i saw was coded into html and when i tried to follow it it was a lot different then what i was use to.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nur791  if this method helps. not sure how to use this to make mana regen go off after a upgrade though.